# How can I isolate the drag constant (C) for vertical motion with quadratic drag from the equation for peak height?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, drag, rocket-science

Some background on my problem: I have calculated the peak height of a rocket (with quadratic drag).  As this will be used for a PID software application, I need to have the equation be expressing peak height, solved for the drag coefficient C. As I am trying to reach a precise apogee, the drag coefficient C is my control variable for the PID I am using for the airbrakes.  The formula is below:

$y_{peak}={\frac{m}{C}}\cdot(\ln (\cos (\tan^{-1} (\frac{v}{\sqrt{\frac{mg}{C}}})))$

Where v is the initial velocity, m is the mass, g is the acceleration of gravity, and c is the drag constant.

I obtained the proof of the formula from [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/quadtpeak.html#c2).

For my application, I need a way to isolate C.  Is this possible?  Is there a work-around? I thought that perhaps going back to the derivation of this equation could help?  Any thoughts? Advice?

Thanks.

Comment: *I need a way to isolate C. Is this possible?* IMHO, that's square NO. Even numerically would be quite hard.

Comment: Yeah, it looks that way to me too, I will probably need to work on a work-around from the PID side of things, and not from the kinematics side.

Comment: It can be rewritten as: $y_{peak}=\frac{m}{C}\ln (\cos (\tan^{-1} (\frac{v}{\sqrt{\frac{mg}{C}}}))$ but it's still impossible to render explicit in $C$.

Comment: Good call, I forgot to simplify that before I posted.

Comment: I'll edit that...